# Can I rollback to previous time point then come back with GitHub in Android Studio 3.5.1?

Tags: git, android-studio, github

I use GitHub in my Android Studio project, I commit two times, there are *A1* and *A2*.

Now I hope to rollback to previous time point *A1* to have a look, I hope the local work area is also *A1* after I rollback.

So I select *'Reset Current Branch to Here'* menu item and choose *'Hard'* option from popup window, you can see *Image 1*. The local work area is *A1* just like I think.

After I finish the look, I hope to come back *A2* with local work area *A2* status, but I find *A2* record dismiss, you can see *Image 2*.

What errors with me?

**Image 1**

[image]

**Image 2**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solving the present problem**

You'd have to reset again to A2 to recover your situation. Since you seem to prefer Android Studio's UI to the CLI, I'd suggest to check your local history to recover the state before your last reset. (But to be noted, in CLI, it would entail to check `git reflog`, spot the hash of the state to recover, then `git reset --hard <hash>`)

---

**Avoiding that situation in the future**

When you have to inspect an older commit, to later return to the current state without modifying recent history, you shouldn't `reset --hard` but rather `checkout` a commit directly.

It will make you enter what's called *detached HEAD state*, which means you're not currently pointing at a branch but directly at a commit in the tree.

When you're done inspecting said commit, to return to A2, just checkout your (`master`) branch again.